# Data from volumes as kubernetes secrets

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have an application that starts with `docker-compose up`. Some ssh credentials are provided with a json file, in a volume, in the host machine. I want to run the app in kubernetes, how can I provide the credentials using kubernetes secrets? my json file looks like:

```
{
  "HOST_USERNAME"="myname",
  "HOST_PASSWORD"="mypass",
  "HOST_IP"="myip"
}
```

I created a file named mysecret.yml with base64 and I applied in kubernetes

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  HOST_USERNAME: c2gaQ=
  HOST_PASSWORD: czMxMDIsdaf0NjcoKik=
  HOST_IP: MTcyLjIeexLjAuMQ==
```

How I have to write the volumes in deployment.yml in order to use the secret properly?

Comment: Have you read [Distribute Credentials Securely Using Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/) in the Kubernetes documentation?  Do you have a partial deployment YAML file you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: redis
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
```

This is the above example of using secret as volumes. You can use the same to define a deployment.

Please refer to official kubernetes documentation for further info:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Comment: This is correct but will not automatically format things as JSON, if you want that specific format it needs to be handled ahead of time.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem! I tried with the above code and it doesn't work. How can I organize the secret to be treated as a json file?

Comment: all needed was `microk8s.kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-file=myvolume/env.json`. The secret yml file was the problem. Thanks